# Sum of strings in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to take the sum of numbers that are formatted as strings in Excel without firstly reformatting them as numbers manually, on row I.

How is this done?

My best attempt so far is

```
=VALUE(SUM(I:I))
```

But does not work :(
Any ideas?

Comment: Does not work unfortunately

Comment: @BigBen Strongly advise not using entire column references! That's processing more than a million cells.

Comment: update: just realized there is a chance for some columns to have text, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Yes, they are. The double unary operator forces it to be evaluated for every single row in the range passed.

Comment: Eh true - still. OP is using entire column. Leave it to OP to adjust the range.

Comment: If you don't believe me then close all workbooks, open a new workbook, put the formula `=SUM(--A:A)` in cell `J1`, then copy to a range of, say, 500 cells, e.g. `J1:AH20`, and watch Excel grind away.

Comment: I think the solution could be to make a function that ignores text values and only takes numbers,  then format those numbers to values and then take the sum, not sure how this is done though

Comment: I don't think a column should have more than one operation, why not use intermediate columns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--I1:I1000,0))
```

[image]

Depending on your version of Excel, may need confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Adjust the range as necessary.

**Note**: `=SUM(IFERROR(--I1:I1000,0))` is a valid (and shorter!) option.

Comment: I confirm in Excel 2007 you need to enter this formula as array formula. Nice one!

Comment: How would you do this if you are to take the sum of something that is in another sheet? Didnt realize this would actually be an issue. Edit: meaning that the I:I row is in another sheet.

Comment: The same way: `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--'Sheet1'!I1:I1000,0))`?

Comment: are you sure that works? for me it then only returns first value of the row i in the sheet

Comment: Make sure to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help. Typed some words and numbers mixed, and formatted all those cells as text.

[image]

My formula in C13 is an array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(A1:A10))=TRUE;VALUE(A1:A10)))
```

Because it's an array formula, it must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>

**IMPORTANT:** Sometimes when referencing cells formatted as text in a formula, the active cell gets formatted to text. So make sure the cell contanining the formula (in my image, C13) is formatted as **Standard**.